# How to implement CORS with dependency injection in Sanic

Tags: python-3.x, sanic

I am building an API in Sanic using the dependency injection library and I am trying to implement CORS.

I have tried to assign the Sanic class to a variable and pass it in the `CORS()`, then pass the variable and `__name__` in the `providers.Factory`.

The comments below show the exact lines where I am trying to implement the CORS:

```py
from sanic_cors import CORS, cross_origin # imported the Sanic_cors here

class Application(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    """
    Application components container
    """
  # declared the app variable here and passed the Sanic class
    app = Sanic()
  # passed the variable in to CORS()
    CORS(app) 
    webapi = providers.Factory(app, __name__)
```

I expected no error on running the API, but I get this error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 7, in <module>
    run_api(APP)
  File "/Users/Kassim/Documents/Projects/pythonProjects/my-app-engine/app/api_runner.py", line 8, in run_api
    web_api = application.webapi()
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pyx", line 100, in dependency_injector.providers.Provider.__call__
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pyx", line 1247, in dependency_injector.providers.Factory._provide
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pxd", line 278, in dependency_injector.providers.__factory_call
  File "src/dependency_injector/providers.pxd", line 272, in dependency_injector.providers.__callable_call
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: As the stacktrace does not contain any part of Sanic, it seems to me, this is rather a question concerning "the dependency inection library" (whatever that is) than a Sanic problem. If you don't get an answer here, maybe go to where the library is developed (github?).

Comment: okay, thanks, found that out later too. [This link helped me solve the CORS issue]
(https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/issues/251#issuecomment-271935799)